# magento 1.9 Wysiwyg cannot see storage subfolder

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, wysiwyg

[image: Cannot see symlinked storage folder]

Cannot see the symlinked storage folder.

Able to create a new folder and upload images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it Fixed

```
var root = new Tree.AsyncTreeNode({
        text: '<?php echo $this->getRootNodeName() ?>',
        draggable:false,
        id:'root',
        children:<?php echo $this->getTreeJson() ?>
    });
```

got it fixed by adding

```
"children:<?php echo $this->getTreeJson() ?>"
```

to the ***tree.phtml*** file .

Answer (score 1):

**Missing folders** : In the folder media, take a look if media/catalog, media/wysiwyg and media/images are there (or even any other folder you’ve set up to upload your files to). If yes, if the server has the permissions to write on them.

**Var/cache** : Get yourself sure you run one `$ rm -rf var/cache/*` and got rid of everything inside this folder.

**Cache Management** : Clean the blocks in System > Cache Management.